# Having several active sandboxes by tag

Tags: discussion

Recently the sandbox was split into several distinct questions ([here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/954/proposed-questions-sandbox-mk-viii-code-golf-only), [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/955/proposed-questions-sandbox-mk-viii-code-challenge-only) and [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/956/proposed-questions-sandbox-mk-viii-miscellaneous)).

For me it feels confusing and we also have the issue that those sandboxes may be handled differently.

- What if the [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) sandbox fills up more quickly? Will we then have different version numbers for each of them?
- What if the puzzle changes its type and becomes [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge) from [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf)? Will it have to move?

It feels even more confusing than a single sandbox with lots of answers (There is the possibility to sort answers by *active* and see the most recent changes on the top).

Therefore, I'd like to vote to close those sandboxes as duplicates. But before doing that I wanted to ask for some discussion of this issue here.

Comment: Another issue is that it now takes up more slots in my feed reader settings, but that's relatively minor.

Comment: I agree. I say keep the code-golf one and edit out the code-golf only bit, then close the other 2 as duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I completely agree. I see absolutely no reason to have separate sandboxes by tags (and the user who has made them has not provided any reason either).

Furthermore, I don't think the user should have simply made this decision without the community's input. This is quite the change from the normal sandbox, and should not have been done so quickly and without a meta post or two about it.

I have voted to close all of them as a duplicate of the previous sandbox (for lack of a better target).

Comment: Although he indeed did that without providing a reason, changes are he was responding to [this comment](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/881/proposed-questions-sandbox-mk-vii#comment3340_881)

Comment: I made that comment because 1. I was commenting on how fast the sandboxes are filling now. 2. I was suggesting that we might need to do something about it; especially if we plan on getting out of beta (non-beta sites get a lot of questions at a fast rate). 3. I was proposing something in attempt to get a discussion going.

Comment: @Quincunx for the next time, the best way to get a discussion is to post a meta question. Today I learned that question marks don't suffice ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak I wasn't too serious about it. I thought that this way, if somebody agreed with me, they could post a discussion. I have to agree; today I learned that for such things, I should make a meta post on it.

Comment: Yes, I was responding to that comment.  Sorry for the problem.  I will remove the duplicates now.